# Excel Conditional Formatting - Find Cells Value in Named Range, check found cell.offset for data

Tags: excel, excel-formula, match, offset, conditional-formatting

Im looking for a non-VBA way of highlighting a cell where its match in a named range does not have a value in its offset cell.

My origin cell is a two digit alpha numeric value, ie: A2. To determine the value to search I am using Left(Origin, 1) to extract the "A" as the value to search the named range for.

The named range "CodeX" covers the range("K3:K12, M3:M12, O3:O12").
I need to find "A" within the named range. Then, when A is found, I need to validate that the cell to the immediate right ie: offset(1, 0) has a value.

Where no value is found, the origin cell is to highlight through conditional formatting. I have attempted Index Match and Countif but not only can i not wrap my head around it, the formulas I've tried don't seem to like that my named range is not all in the one column.

I can do this via VBA, but would prefer not to as it screws around with other conditional formatting already in place.

Comment: Columns K, M and O are different areas within the CodeX named range.  `=INDEX(CodeX,,,2)` will reference the second area within your range.  So something like `=OFFSET(INDEX(CodeX,MATCH(LEFT(Origin,1),INDEX(CodeX,,1,2),0),1,2),,1)` would return the value to the right of area 2 if it exists, #N/A if the letter doesn't exist and 0 if the letter exists, but no value.  Not a complete answer, but may help you on your way.

Answer (score 0):

That's a beast of a formula you're looking for. Here you go:

```
=IFERROR(INDIRECT("R"&ROW()&"C"&IF(
    ISNUMBER(FIND("A",INDEX(CodeX,ROW(),1,1))),
        COLUMN(INDEX(CodeX,ROW(),1,1))+1,
        IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("A",INDEX(CodeX,ROW(),1,2))),
            COLUMN(INDEX(CodeX,ROW(),1,2))+1,
            IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("A",INDEX(CodeX,ROW(),1,3))),
                COLUMN(INDEX(CodeX,ROW(),1,3))+1,
                FALSE
))),FALSE)="",TRUE)
```

It's checking the current row for each of the 3 areas in range `CodeX` for that string `A`. If it finds it, it returns the column number of the cell tor the right, or else it checks the next area.

It uses the current row and the column number to find the value of the cell to the right of the matched cell. If the value is `""` the cell is empty and your originating cell should be highlighted. If there is an error, `A` was not found and originating cell should be highlighted.

Edit: Here is the explanation:

`INDEX(CodeX,ROW(),1,1)` gets a reference to CodeX, current row, column 1, range group 1.

`FIND("A",INDEX(CodeX,ROW(),1,1))` returns where (index number) string "A" is in the reference cell. If there is no "A", it returns an error.

`ISNUMBER(FIND("A",INDEX(CodeX,ROW(),1,1)))` returns `TRUE` if "A" was found and `FALSE` if not.

`COLUMN(INDEX(CodeX,ROW(),1,1))+1` gets the column to the right of the reference.

`INDIRECT("R"&ROW()&"C"&...,FALSE)` gets the reference to the current row and 1 column to the right of "A" if found. If "A" was not found, it returns an error. the `FALSE` tells excel my reference type is in the R1C1 format.

`=IFERROR(...="",TRUE)` returns `TRUE` if the cell to the right of "A" equals `""`, `FALSE` if it as any value other than `""` and it its an error ("A" was not found), returns `TRUE`.

Comment: Thank you so much Dave. This is perfect.

Comment: @Lou, I edited my post to explain the formula so you can modify as needed.